# How to select certain text from a textarea element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, select

I'm trying to select some text from a textarea element using javascript. For example, I that this text in a textarea element "Today is the first day of the week" the user click a button to select the work "Today" so they can change it for any text.

[image]

I konw that by doing element.select() I can select the entire content of the textarea, Is there another function or code that I can use to select only a work or a number or character within a textarea?

Comment: Thank you @Phiter

Comment: Check my answer and see if it's what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` here is simple sample on click it will select text based on where you clicked

```js
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var length = this.value.length;
    this.setSelectionRange(this.selectionStart, length);
},
false);
```

```html
<textarea  id="text"  value="" size="20" >EXAMPLE</textarea >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to select the desired text inside of a textarea. For the selection to work, you have to set focus on the textarea first.

```js
var $_ = function(selector){
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function selectText(str) {
  var txt = $_("#txt");
  var idx = txt.value.indexOf(str);
  txt.focus();
  txt.setSelectionRange(idx, idx + str.length);
}

$_("#btnSelect").addEventListener('click', function() {
  selectText($_("#selectWord").value);
});
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="txt" cols="30" rows="10">Today is gonna be the day that they're gonna throw it back to you.</textarea>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="selectWord" value="gonna" />
<button id="btnSelect">Select</button>
```